# Movie with a demon that forcibly impregnates women

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember only a little part of the whole movie, but I'll try to give the most details I can.

This is what I remember of the movie:

- Contemporary setting
- It follows a man and maybe a woman who seem to work together or be connected through their job.
- Maybe they have some sort of connection with the police but I'm really not sure.
- At some point they find an old (not sure) nun who got pregnant without being touched by any man.
- There is a scene with a pregnant woman in a hospital bed (not sure if it really was a hospital). They see the baby through ultrasound and she gets scared and wants to get rid of it. It was implied, and possibly stated outright, that she was attacked and impregnated by some sort of demon. I think it was told that there were other women who had had the same thing happen to them.

About when I watched it:

- Watched it on French TV
- I do remember it was a multi-part movie but I'm not sure. It was broadcast until late at night, I couldn't watch all of it since I needed to get up early.
- Maybe broadcast in early 2000
- Saw it in French but doesn't mean it was a French movie

If I do remember anything else I'll add it.

Comment: May I ask why the downvotes so I can improve my question?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's solely due to the mention of rape, particularly in the title (where you spelled it wrong). Questions regarding topics like that tend to be very poorly-received here, though this one is well-written otherwise. I'll see if I can sanitise it a bit without removing any important details.

Comment: Thank you, I thought it might be the cause but, even if it's not the main topic of the movie, it the main thing I do remember of this movie and I couldn't find any other way to say it. And sorry for the misspelling. English is not my primary language so I tried my best.

Comment: https://atomtickets.com/movie-news/the-child-remains-review/ matches, but that was just in theatres.

Comment: Do you remember who the actors were? Because it sounds somewhat like the movie The End of Days, with Arnold Schwarzenegger  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_Days_(film)

Answer (score 3):

There was an episode of X- Files that was similar.  It wasn’t a movie, but it was from the mid to late 90’s.  A pregnant woman is in a hospital and the ultra sound reveals strange abnormalities.  The woman is scared and claims she was raped by some kind of creature or demon.  Mulder and Scully investigate and find a demon posing as a human to impregnate human women.

Comment: https://x-files.fandom.com/wiki/Die_Hand_Die_Verletzt?

Comment: @ScoopsTroop The episode you're thinking of is Terms of Endearment: https://x-files.fandom.com/wiki/Terms_of_Endearment  I watched it recently and it certainly fits